# change edge color in fill_between function of matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, colors

I am using `fill_between` to fill the color in the chart. But colors of the edges are still random(red and blue as shown in the picture). How can I change the color of the each edge?

```
plt.plot(x, y1, x, y2, x, y3, x, y4) 
plt.fill_between(x, y1, 0, color='gray')
plt.fill_between(x, y2, y1, color='red') 
plt.fill_between(x, y3, y2, color='yellow')
plt.fill_between(x, y4, y3, color='green')
plt.margins(0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The lines are produced by `plt.plot(..)`, remove it if you don't want to have it.

Comment: I didnt notice that plt.plot() is not required. Removing it  worked!!